AG Grid Community - Angular extend-theme scss not supporting `material-dark`
When using the ag-grid-community styles mixins to extend a theme I get a build error when trying to use material-dark.
The error states that material-dark is an invalid extend-theme. However it provides a list of themes that can be extended and it is amongst the list.
Build Error
I am using the latest version of ag-grid-angular.
"ag-grid-angular": "^32.2.2",
I've tried changing to other themes on the list and they all work expect the material-dark.
I have even just tried using the grid with the material-dark theme directly and this does indeed work.
So it appears the only issue is it cannot be extended even though it states that it's in the supported themes for extending.
